# how to execute Sql server stored procedure using Ms-Access form by passing parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

i need to develop Access form to pass parameters to call Sql Server Stored procedure.and need to show output.
Ex: i have two parameters " Start Date " And " End Date "
     from Access form i need to pass these dates and excute Sql server Stored procedure and output should display..

Please help me...Please help me step by step,I am new to This Access application

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your stored procedure output type, but basically, say you want to display the result of your stored procedure `myProc` to the debug console, you could do something like:

```vb
Sub printMyProcResults(startDate as Date, endDate as Date)
    Dim db as DAO.Database
    Dim qf as DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs as DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb()        
    Set qf = db.CreateQueryDef("")
    ' Set to true if your stored procedure returns something, otherwise, '
    ' set to False '
    qf.ReturnsRecords = True

    ' You need to adjust this to whatever your SQL server instance name is '
    ' and whatever your database name is '
    ' This connection string will use the local machine's user credentials '
    ' to connect to the server, change as appropriate '
    qf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MYSERVER;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=MYDATABASE;"

    ' We construct the SQL to call the procedure. Update this to suit your '
    ' actual proc name '
    qf.SQL = "myStoredProc '" & Format(startDate, "dd mmm yyyy") & "'," & _
                          "'" & Format(endDate, "dd mmm yyyy") & "'" 

    ' Open the recordset to access the results '
    Set rs = qf.OpenRecordSet()

    ' Print the result to the debug console '
    ' Of course, you need to adapt this to your own case '
    Do While Not rs.EOF
       debug.print rs(0)
       rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    ' Cleanup ' 
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

For the connection string, you may need to adapt it to your own settings, depending on how your SQL Server is configured: http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: i want pass parameters from access to sql server stored procedure using access form and should get output in Access..please help in detailsed step

Comment: The above code has a few issues in it.  db is defined twice.  query is spelt wrong 'CreateQeuryDef'.  Also ReturnRecords  I believe should be ReturnsRecords

Comment: @ChrisNevill code was updated with your comments. Thanks for pointing out the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in access years ago. You would need to look at pass through ODBC queries. This will allow you to execute SQL stored procedure from Access.

Please see this link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968

I am not sure how you will get the parameters passed through though but I am sure if you google " pass through odbc query access stored procedure parameters " you will find some hints. Sorry my memory is a bit faded about the exact details.

Comment: but how to connect sql server 2008 from Access form to call stored procedure and pass parametes.what is the steps to do that.i created form with 2 test boxes(startdate,enddate) and one button.then next what to do to pass parameters to Sql server stared procedure and get output

Comment: You need a ODBC connection from access to SQL go to this link and read  it http://accessexperts.net/blog/2011/07/29/sql-server-stored-procedure-guide-for-microsoft-access-part-1/

Comment: i created odbc connection in controlpanel-> administrative tool.I unable to figure it out how to move next to excute Sp in sql server by passing parameters from Access from and get output

Comment: please try to guid me  i hanged here

Comment: Firstly can you create a ODBC connection to the SQL server? Did you try and create a connection string? See this link for more examples http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892490 I dont have access on my computer as I am running Ubuntu so I wont be able to directly guide you at the moment. You will need to create a connection first by using ODBC then you can pass your query via this connection to the SQL server.

Comment: i created odbc connection to the sql server with valid authentications. but what to do next?